# Event and mysqldump

Tags: mysql, events, database-backups

I am trying to create an event for automatic backup using this code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS e_AutomaticBackUp1Day
ON SCHEDULE AT 1 Day STARTS '2020-07-06 10:13:00'
DO
BEGIN
mysqldump -u user -p password dbname > E:BackUp.sql
END

$$
```

But I am getting an error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'day STARTS '2020-07-06 10:13:00'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do "AT" followed by a delay, do either AT 'date', or EVERY 'delay' :

So

```
ON SCHEDULE AT '2020-07-06 10:13:00'
```

Or

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2020-07-06 10:13:00'
```